# Real Managers in Career Mode - FIFA 17

Tags: fifa-17

Is there a way to play career mode, but as the real manager of a team?

Example: Play career mode with Liverpool, and have Jurgen Klopp be the manager, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. Although I agree this would be a cool feature. The only way you could do it is play one season on tournament mode instead of career mode, then it should show Klopp as the manager.